# if condition with jquery

Tags: jquery

In my jQuery, am getting the student details which from the autocomplete selected item, like

```
var data = "<div class='close'><table><tr><td rowspan='4' width='50px;'>
     <img src='" + studentItem.Photo + "' Width='48' Height='48'  /></td><td>" + 
     studentItem.Name + " ( <span class='stuId'>" + studentItem.StudentId + 
     "</span> )</td><td align='right' ><div class='close16'/></td></tr><tr><td>
     <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><td>" + studentItem.Email +
     "</td><td>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</td><td>" + studentItem.Mobile + "</td></tr></table>
     </td></tr></table></td></tr></table></div>";
```

and am binding this `data` to a div tag like

```
$("#students").append(data);
```

The problem here is I can get the same student again and again, and I can bind the same data again and again into this div tag.

So to restrict this I tried to set the condition before the `data` like,

```
if (!$('.stuId').is(studentItem.StudentId)) {
   var data=..........
}
else{
  alert('Duplicate data');
}
```

but its goin into the block even if the studentId already there in the div. How can I fix this, can anyone help me here

Comment: `.is()` doesn't compare contents, it compares selectors.

Comment: Here's [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), it's a great place to demonstrate code in action to reproduce the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: thanks Juhana & David, I'll check it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we don't know what kind of `StudentId` you have, we can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (however, in some cases [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) might be enough):

```
var len = $('.stuId').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML == studentItem.StudentId;
}).length;

if (len == 0) {
    var data = ..........
} else {
    alert('Duplicate data');
}​
```

It will select all `.stuId` elements and filter the duplicates.

Comment: thaks alottt VisioN, this is exactly I wanted...thans again

Comment: @Shanish, then you definitely need to use `filter`. `:contains` selector will work partially. You are welcome!

Comment: Vision, is it possible to check for string values, just the same way we r checking numeric values here, am passing values like 'Semester1','Semester2'... is it possible to restrict this

Comment: @Shanish Yes sure. The solution should successfully work with strings.